# numpy suddenly started failing to import

Tags: python, numpy

I have anaconda installed. Running python 2.7. I have uninstalled, reinstalled, and upgraded numpy to 1.11.0, uninstalled and reinstalled pandas, and I still get this traceback when I try to import numpy:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Users/nicole/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/numpy/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
        from . import add_newdocs
      File "/Users/nicole/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
        from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
      File "/Users/nicole/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from .type_check import *
      File "/Users/nicole/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
        import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
      File "/Users/nicole/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
        from numpy.testing.nosetester import _numpy_tester
      File "/Users/nicole/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/numpy/testing/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
        from . import decorators as dec
      File "/Users/nicole/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/numpy/testing/decorators.py", line 21, in <module>
        from .utils import SkipTest
      File "/Users/nicole/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 15, in <module>
        from tempfile import mkdtemp, mkstemp
      File "/Users/nicole/anaconda/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 35, in <module>
        from random import Random as _Random
      File "random/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
        from .mtrand import *
      File "numpy.pxd", line 92, in init mtrand         (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:37726)
```

It was working fine last night, which is really frustrating. Thank you for any insight.

Comment: What are your files named?

Comment: random.py, haha. I changed it and it works. Thank you so much, I feel like a dingus. But why did it work last night, then?

Comment: Do you have a folder named random in your working directory?

Edit: A few seconds late...